# Link_to that deletes polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble figuring out how to delete my subscription for a product when my models are:

```
class User
  has_many :products
  has_many :subscriptions, :foreign_key => :subscriber_id
end

class Product
  has_many :subscriptions, :as => :subscribable
end

class Subscription
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :subscribable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And I try to delete by my view and controller setup:

```
def unsubscribe_product
  @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  if @subscription.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  else
    redirect_to :back
  end
end

<td><%= link_to "Unsubscribe", { :controller => "products", 
                                 :action => "unsubscribe_product", 
                                 :id => subscription.id }, 
                                 :method => :delete %></td>
```

But get the error:

```
NameError in Pages#subscribe_area

undefined local variable or method `subscription' for #<#<Class>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work this way. I have an instance to find the subscription. Why can't I use it? Will this automatically map to the current users subscriptions too?

Thanks, could use the help.

---

Edit

**PagesController** & **pages/subscribe_area.html.erb**

```
def subscribe_area
    @products = current_user.products
end

<table>
 <% for product in @products %>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', product, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    <% if current_user.subscribed_for?(product) %>
       <td><%= link_to "Unsubscribe", { :controller => "products", :action => "unsubscribe_product", :id => subscription.id }, :method => :delete %></td>
    <% else %>
       <td><%= link_to "Subscribe", { :controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id }, :method => :post %></td>
    <% end %>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though subscription in the link should be `@subscription` saying you are declaring it in your controller.  Else I would need to see the whole page code as well as the action that renders it

Updated:
So you are not defining subscription.  Try this instead:

```
<td><%= link_to "Unsubscribe", { :controller => "products", :action => "unsubscribe_product", :id => product.id }, :method => :delete %></td>
```

Then modify your action as follows:

```
def unsubscribe_product
  product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @subscription = product.subscriptions.find_by_subscriber_id(current_user.id)
  if @subscription.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  else
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```